# Is my salary Halaal or Haram

Tags: halal-haram

Let us say I am an employee and the type of work I do is Halal. Means, I have sold my 8 working hours to my employer for doing the halal work and getting paid for this.

Now what if

1. I don't do my tasks honestly and spent the time doing my personal
   things and delay the task deliberately?
2. I have got my task done and now i spent my spare time doing personal
   things?
3. There is no check and balance, i can do a task in 2 hours but i do
   it in 4 hours and spent 2 hours playing on internet?

Is my salary Halal or Haram?
I have heard that the Salary is Halal but I will be held responsible for dishonesty/cheating/stealing.

Comment: I'm certain I've seen a video or two by Ustadh Nouman Ali Khan that mention commitment, and he makes citations, I'm sure. Also please see the ProductiveMuslim website if you've finding yourself with spare time at work.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the details of your contract or agreements with your employer. If your employer has no problem with personal use of internet so there is no problem.

> وَلَا تَقْرَ‌بُوا مَالَ الْيَتِيمِ إِلَّا بِالَّتِي هِيَ أَحْسَنُ
>   حَتَّىٰ يَبْلُغَ أَشُدَّهُ ۚ وَأَوْفُوا بِالْعَهْدِ ۖ إِنَّ الْعَهْدَ
>   كَانَ مَسْئُولًا
>
> And do not approach the property of an orphan, except in the way that
>   is best, until he reaches maturity. **And fulfill [every] commitment.
>   Indeed, the commitment is ever [that about which one will be]
>   questioned.** http://tanzil.net/#17:34

Any small promise/contract/commitment will be questioned at judgement day. Also you should believe that the only one who feed you is God and not your employer and you can change your job if there is better opportunity that you can pay to your family costs and religion better than before. For example starting a business.

> وَفِي السَّمَاءِ رِ‌زْقُكُمْ وَمَا تُوعَدُونَ
>
> And in the heaven is your provision and whatever you are promised.
>   http://tanzil.net/#51:22
>
> and do not kill your children out of poverty; **We will provide for you**
>   and them. http://tanzil.net/#6:151

Your income is in heaven with God and not in pocket of your boss.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I don't do my tasks honestly and spent the time doing my personal things and delay the task deliberately?

Answer: Your salary will not become haram in this case, unless you do some actions, which really make it haram. Like you are dealing in haram actions, you steal at work. If you do not spend time properly, then its called Dis-Honesty, which comes under Dis-liked section, and not haram.

> I have got my task done and now i spent my spare time doing personal
>   things?

Ans: Nothing wrong in it, because you are not doing any harm to anyone or not doing anything Un-Islamic or somethng, which your company does not allow you at all, or it harms the company in serious way.

> There is no check and balance, i can do a task in 2 hours but i do it
>   in 4 hours and spent 2 hours playing on internet?

Ans: Again this comes under Dis-honesty. its better to avoid it, but it does not makes your salary haram in any way.

(Note: All above are my personal opinions, and i am not a scholar, it would be best to consult a scholar in this case for detailed answer)

And Allah knows the best